# How can I get this question that's been dup hammered re-opened?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

The question [Why does strcmp give back non-deterministic results when called with 2 equivalent styles on GCC on Linux and in Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37695188/6292850) (N.B. not my question) was recently closed as a duplicate of [strcmp() return different values for same string comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091350/strcmp-return-different-values-for-same-string-comparisons).

I argued that it's not a duplicate because:

- It affects a specific version branch and OP's code doesn't reproduce the problem on the compiler version used in the duplicate
- The two questions are different. One is called `strcmp()` directly, while OP's code is passing it to a wrapper function that takes `const void*` arguments. This changes the semantics of the program.

Then I posted 4 demos illustrating that the duplicate does not solve OP's problem despite the gold badger insisting that it does without proof:

- [Demo 1](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4Px51XZffSVdjY7j) illustrating OP's original code on 5.3.0
- [Demo 2](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/6VqPbHtoy7WGf1s6) showing a small modification to OP's code, using `const char[]` variables instead of passing string literals directly to the wrapper function
- [Demo 3](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ZN8tzmpAoCvwK7Ed) using `-fno-builtin` as suggested in the duplicate with Demo 2.
- [Demo 4](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/AXcmZKQIm6Dl62rM) using `-fno-builtin` with OP's original code.

All demonstrate the problem. For reference, here are the gold badger's three comments:

> It is an exact dup. The first answer explains the reason for this are
>   intrinsic functions, and the second explains the return values
>
> The solution in the dup solves this problem.
>
> As has been said above and in the dup, `-fno-builtin` solves this

I personally believe the gold badger is being stubborn and is insinuating the question is a duplicate without proof, in spite of my comments showing the problem still exists despite applying the duplicate's solutions. Can we get this reopened please?

I could edit this into OP's question but I don't want to deface their question. Furthermore, it would be pointless unless they themselves do in fact agree with the results of the tests.